# webfont otf instead of ttf

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Somefont;
  src: url('fonts/somefont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/somefont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/somefont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/somefont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/somefont.svg#Somefont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;   
}
```

This is the css we usually use for embedding a font on a webpage.

I am a font designer and therefore I know (and have seen) that the curves of ttf are distorted always a bit when the design was converted from an otf font. (I use fontsquirrel Web font generator).

Is there a way to replace the whole ttf file with the otf and is this reliable on all browsers specially webkit?

I made some experiments and found it quite confusing to say which data is actually used by specific browsers.
What I want to achieve is to abolish as much as possible the ttf files in the favor of otf.

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: Aw, six months, without even as much as a single comment. Shame. If I understand you correctly, you want 1) to know if you can use otf fonts in the font-face clause, and the answer is, you sure can try! `format('opentype')`, give it a go. And 2) if you use a compound statement such as this, how to see which file the browser actually uses. My suggestion would be, put all different fonts in here (like serif.eot, sans.woff, mono.ttf etc) and you can easily see on the screen which one gets displayed.